# Why I get unsorted columns in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

The DataGridView is filled from DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt = serviceSqlite.select();

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Where `select` method has the following fields sequence in `SELECT`:

```
                "Pacients.id, " +
                "unique_code," +
                "status_pass, " +
                "payment, " +
                "profession," +
                "office_address, " +
                "factory_name, " +
                "factory_edrpou, " +
                "factory_departament," +
                "name, " +
                "secondname, " +
                "lastname, " +
                "datebirth, " +
                "taxcode, " +
                "gender, " +
                "Pacients.created_at, " +
                "PacientsOrder.kind_work, " +
                "PacientsOrder.status "
```

Also in properties of DataTable I moves columns name like this:

[image]

Why I get unsorted columns in DataGridView when program is launched? The sequence of columns is not as I have set in properties.

Comment: What properties do you have on `dataGridView1`? Have you set the columns on there?

Comment: I just sorted columns in DataGridView. But it does not work for me. You can see names of colums in pic

Comment: Use `DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex` to sort your `DataGridViewColumns`. Also you can turn `AutoGenerateColumns` (not visible property in Designer) to False and create the Columns/DataBindings yourself before you bind the `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetOrdinal` for `DataTable` columns, to display the columns in specific order.

Do this to `DataTable` before binding it to the `DataGridView`.

ex:

```
//Assuming Name,Place,Country,Continent are four columns.

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//YOU HAVE YOUR DATA TABLE LOADED AND YOU KNOW COLUMN NAMES.

//USE setOrdinal FOR DISPLAYING THEM IN ORDER. 
dt.Columns["Name"].SetOrdinal(0);
dt.Columns["Country"].SetOrdinal(1);
dt.Columns["Continent"].SetOrdinal(2);
dt.Columns["Place"].SetOrdinal(3);
```

After binding it to `DataGridView`, when you run the application you can see the columns displayed as Name,Country,Continent,Place.

Comment: I'd not recommend to use SetOrdinal to define the display order. I'd rather use DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex property

Comment: Ya. But if his datagrid is empty before binding datatable.... He may have tough time to use displayindex

Comment: I can not see problems changing the DisplayIndex after binding the DataGridView. Besides that; In my opinion `AutoGenerateColumns` is a terrible property to leave on.